# Playing Quran on water

Tags: miracles, blessings-of-allah

Salamo'alaikom. Is it true that playing Quran over regular water makes that water become like ZamZam water in quality?

**Please don't flag this question too, Jazakom Allah**

Answer (score 1):

**No, that's not true.**

[Zamzam water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamzam_Well) is not any water, it is a miraculously-generated source of water from God, and it only comes out of the spring found in Mecca, Saudi Arabia, and nowhere else.

If the water you are talking about came from another source (i.e., another spring), then that's enough reason for it to not be Zamzam nor to have the property to be transformed to Zamzam.

Comment: Ah ok.thanks. Coz i've seen in a video that playing it on regular water makes it like zamzam water (i.e speech of Allah makes it LIKE zamzam water)

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to share the link by attaching it to your question, so we can have a look at and comment about it

Answer (score 0):

Zamzama water is a holy water in Muslims culture.
But if you reciting quran pak on water it becomes pure and carries (shifa) in it.
But it's not good to said that a regular water converts into zamzama water by playing on it 
Yes their is another situation 
 if you pour a drop of zamzama water in a tank of regular water now its all tank become a zamzama water.
Hope this will makes sense for you.